# matplotlib scatter shifts color codes when NaN is present

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I want to plot some data with a given color code. For example:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3])
colors = np.array(['g', 'r', 'b', 'y'])
plt.scatter(x, b**2, color=colors)
```

Great, all the points appear, each one with its color.
Now, some data is missing:

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, np.log10(b), color=colors)
```

Here comes the problem: the x=1 data is missing (log(0)=NaN), but the colors are skipping this point and the x=2 point is red, not blue.
The solution can be:

```
y = np.log10(b)
mask = np.isfinite(y)
plt.scatter(x[mask], y[mask], color=colors[mask])
```

but I feel it so uncomfortable to do this... Any other way?

Comment: That seems like a pretty good way.  Can you report that as an issue on github?  It seems wrong to me that the data gets masked, but the other inputs do not.

Comment: OK, thanks, I just did it.

Answer (score 2):

Using c instead of color solves the problem:

```
plt.scatter(x, np.log10(b), c=colors)
```

Thanks to the github people:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3489

C.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer when the system will let you.

Comment: This is a old question, but I just got here for the same problem. It's worth noting that this correction does not work for older version of matplotlib. (I'm on a system using 2.0.0 for whatever reason, even though that's no longer current.)